# Can we use more than one SurfaceView in same Activity in android?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I am new in Android. I want to know Can we use more than one SurfaceView  in same Activity in android?

If anybody knows then please tell me how?

I am stuck on this issues.

Thanks.

Comment: if you get the answer please tell me because you know that i have tried very hard for surfaceview in dualcamera app

Answer (score 1):

I have not did it but try this..May it possible

```
 For example 

 LinearLayout ll1=new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout ll2=new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout ll3=new LinearLayout(this);
    ll1.addView(surfaceview1ObjectFirst);
    ll2.addView(surfaceview1ObjectSecond);
    ll3.addView(surfaceview1ObjectThird);
```

**Updated**

You can add more than one surfaceView inside one activity. Add them just like you add other view inside ViewGroup

Comment: these are linear views however, he was asking for surfaceviews

Comment: Yes i know he is asking about srufaceview. So i explain you can add more than one surface view inside one screen

Answer (score 0):

You can't have more than one `SurfaceView` in a Window.
A `SurfaceView` punches a "hole" in the current window (seethrough) and places its own window below the current window where it can draw itself.
You can't have several "holes" in the same window.
If you need to use several `SurfaceViews`, create a `Dialog` for each one and place them inside the `Dialog`.